# TinyMCE Only allow elements that have a specific class

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want every `div` element in TinyMCE to be removed, except if it has one of the following classes:

- typewrite
- ad
- mceNonEditable

I'm using the following settings in my TinyMCE configuration to try and achieve this, but it still keeps certain `div` elements that do not have any of these classes.

```
valid_elements: 'div[class=typewrite|ad|mceNonEditable]',

valid_classes: {
    'div': 'typewrite ad mceNonEditable',
},
```

For example, a TinyMCE instance is initiated with the following content:

```
<div class="typewrite">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<p>Some editable content</p>
<p>Some editable content</p>
<div class="unwanted-tag" data-url="http://localhost/"></div>
<p>Some editable content</p>
```

In the TinyMCE editor, this will parse to:

```
<div class="typewrite">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<p>Some editable content</p>
<p>Some editable content</p>
<div data-url="http://localhost/">
    <br>
</div>
<p>Some editable content</p>
```

So it does remove the unwanted class, but actually keeps the element.

Is there any way to delete these unwanted elements, other than manually removing them with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

No, afaik there is no other way.

To remove those elements on startup is not that difficult though.